# Which wires goes to appliance's ground and on/off switch?

Tags: ground, wire, plug

I have an electric hair trimmer whose power kept getting interrupted.  I knew the problem was in a particular spot in the cord because when it would bend there, the trimmer would lose power.  I cut the cord at that spot and discovered one of the wires inside the outer black insulating rubber was broken.  My plan was just to strip the outer black insulating rubber and re-splice the two wires together and then cover the area back up with a few layers of electrical tape.  Problem is I forgot to label the wires before I cut them and now I'm not sure which wires coming from the plug go to which wires that are attached to the cutter.  Is it that the wire belonging to the wider prong on the plug goes to the trimmer's ground and the wire belonging to the narrower prong goes to the trimmer's on/off switch?  What happens if it's wired backwards - does it just not work or is it dangerous?  Would I get electrocuted?

Comment: A mains cord spliced with electrical tape sounds like a good way to damage yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The Live (thin blade) should be switch-controlled. The Neutral (thick blade) should be connected to ground. Reversing them could potentially be fatal.